# Target orientation of iOS6 shouldAutorotate

Tags: cocoa, ios6

i want to allow the should rotate, based on the target orientation

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]
```

however the code above, when used in shouldRotate holds the current (old) orientation, not the target orientation

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate {

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I figured it out. Return YES in shouldAutorotate always and then do this:

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
        // Allow if you can
    } else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) {
        // Allow if you can
    }
    // so on
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
```

This method should do the trick for you.
The toInterfaceOrientation holds the target orientation.

Comment: can you please upgrade the answer... those who have downgraded my other answer...

Answer (score -1):

Apart from returning yes to

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
return YES;
}
```

you have to implement

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

Different Masks that are available are:

```
UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait
UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft
UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight
UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown
UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape
UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll
UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown
```

You may also like to see:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/supportedInterfaceOrientations

Comment: yes i know, but thats not an ansewer to my problem :( how to detect the target orientation

Comment: The OP asked how to detect the target orientation, we already know we should return YES if we want to auto-rotate.